# Decode UDP message (from Erlang to Java)

Tags: java, erlang, udp

I just tried to send a message by UDP from an Erlang server to a Java client. Now I am wondering how I should do to interpret this message to something useful.

Here is what I wrote in Erlang:

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(8789, [binary, {active, true}]).
gen_udp:send(Socket, {127,0,0,1},11001, "yeah!").
```

And here is my Java code:

public class Server {

```
private DatagramSocket socket;
private byte[] buffer;

public Server() {
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(11001);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    buffer = new byte[65508];
}

public void receivePackage() {
    try {

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        byte[] buffer = packet.getData();

        System.out.println(buffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

How do I handle the byte buffer and translate it to something that I can output in the Java console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the Erlang side try to send 
binary instead of string :

```
gen_udp:send(Socket, {127,0,0,1},11001, <<"yeah!">>).
```

On java side:

```
byte[] b1 = new byte[] {#your byte array};
String s2 = new String(b1);
```

This will parse binary data to string.

Comment: Is that the same as sending it as an atom? How big would my byte array have to be?

Comment: You already have the byte array here: `byte[] buffer = packet.getData();`. You just need to create a string from it: `String s = new String(buffer)`. And you should probably use a charset as the second parameter of the String constructor.